# Make animation with several div's in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sequence

I have a working animation jquery script here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usa0w2r6/)

```
var speed = 1500;
var margin = 50;
var start = 200;
var next = 1400;

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#foo").show().animate({
        // marginLeft: startPoint,
        marginLeft: margin // endPoint
    }, speed);
},start + next * 0);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#bar").show().animate({
        // marginLeft: startPoint,
        marginLeft: margin // endPoint
    }, speed);
},start + next * 1);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#foobar").show().animate({
        // marginLeft: startPoint,
        marginLeft: margin // endPoint
    }, speed);
},start + next * 2);
```

I would like to change all the div id's into classes and then run a loop in jquery instead - similar to this: [animating-several-divs-in-a-sequence](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q9qG/).

```
$(function () {
    function show() {
        $('.project_box:not(.completed):first').show(500, function () {
            $(this).addClass('completed');
            show();
        });
    }

    show();
});
```

I would also like to run the animation from outside the body-tag ("startPoint") and make it end at its current "endPoint".

Any help is much appreciated!

Note: Please have in mind, that I'm a newbie into jQuery and English is not my spoken language. :-)

Comment: Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/ncbwrxtm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here suppose you name the class as `class="test"`. you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var speed = 1500;
    var margin = 50;
    var start = 200;
    var next = 1400;
    $('.test').each(function(index,element){
        setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).show().animate({
            // marginLeft: startPoint,
            marginLeft: margin // endPoint
            }, speed);
        },start + next * index);
    });


});
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/w7o0vezs/

Comment: Use saved my day (and hair)! :-D


Thank you very much for a quick and indeed very usefull reply! :-)

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to vote yet, but I will when ever I can.

The issue with the starting point has been solved using css and negative margin.

Case closed! :-)


Regards,

Munding

Comment: See! I was so happy that I wrote "Use" instead of "You"!?

One of those brain-farts...  lol :-D